# How to bower install the unstable version of Angular UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

A better pagination is implemented in ui-grid. The [demo](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination) looks good. But it is using an unstable version.

When I check the bower packages by

```
bower info angular-ui-grid
```

The latest found is #3.0.0-RC.18.

After a bower install:

```
bower install angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18
```

I find no `unstable.js` to use. And the `ui-grid.js` installed contains no functions like `enablePaginationControls`. Obviously, that **unstable** version is not installed.

So, what is the correct way to obtain the **unstable** file?

---

Just checked the GitHub page [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release), and found there is a new update.

We don't want to just bower install a single file, which defeats the purpose of package management.

How is it possible to bower install version **3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30**?

I tried:

```
bower install angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30 --save
```

And here is the error:

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30
bower ENORESTARGET  No tag found that was able to satisfy 3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30

Additional error details:
Available versions: 3.0.0-rc.16, 3.0.0-rc.15, 3.0.0-rc.14, 3.0.0-rc.13, 3.0.0-rc.12, 3.0.0-rc.11, 3.0.0-rc.10, 3.0.0-rc.8, 3.0.0-rc.7, 3.0.0-RC.18
```

Comment: Related link about adding unstable version for bower usage https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3337

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the one file, you can use this command to download it:

```
bower install --save https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/blob/gh-pages/release/ui-grid-unstable.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But is that really the way we should go? That command will place the file under a `ui-grid-unstable` folder.

Comment: This works fine, but link to the raw file:  `bower install --save https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/ui-grid-unstable.js`

Answer (score 0):

Now there is also the bower package.

https://libraries.io/bower/ui-grid-unstable